# Unify moderator's pages navigation

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, navigation

1. There is nav tab on several pages:

   > [image]
2. On some pages (e.g. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/admin/community-events) the are breadcrumbs:

   > [image]
3. Others (e.g. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/admin/merge-questions) don't have any navigation at all:

   > [image]

Could you unify the navigation on moderator's pages?