# Inconsistent/confusing breadcrumb navigation on some moderator tools pages

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, navigation

Moderators have access to a couple of tools via the `/admin/links` page. There is some inconsistency in the breadcrumb navigation for the different pages, which I noticed after being puzzled by the one for Community Events. I think an entry 'Community Events' should be between 'Admin' and 'Upcoming' (or 'Past', depending on which tab is selected)

[image]

Other inconsistencies include: a `->` being used as separator, and the final entry not being clickable:

[image]

Some pages don't have a breadcrumb navigation at all:

[image]

or even completely lack a title:

[image]

Comment: Very similar: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331876/282094 - since I don't have access to the pages I'll refrain from calling it a dupe.